# Getting the numeric values of a file on C++

Tags: c++, file

I'm trying to make a high score board that remembers the values from the previous games. It saves the files correctly, but it erases them whenever its reopened.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

void buildHighScore(){
    int score1 = 0;
    int score2 = 0;
    int score3 = 0;
    int score4 = 0;
    int score5 = 0;
    int score0;
    cout<<"What is your score? \n";
    cin>>score0;
    if (score0 > score1){
        score5 = score4;
        score4 = score3;
        score3 = score2;
        score2 = score1;
        score1 = score0;
    }
    else if (score0 > score2){
        score5 = score4;
        score4 = score3;
        score3 = score2;
        score2 = score0;
    }
    else if (score0 > score3){
        score5 = score4;
        score4 = score3;
        score3 = score0;
    }
    else if (score0 > score4){
        score5 = score4;
        score4 = score0;
    }
    else if (score0 > score5){
        score5 = score0;
    }
    fstream highscores;
    highscores.open("Highscores.txt");
    highscores<<
    "1. "<<score1<<"\n"
    "2. "<<score2<<"\n"
    "3. "<<score3<<"\n"
    "4. "<<score4<<"\n"
    "5. "<<score5<<"\n";
    highscores.close();
}
```

The problem is whenever the program executes the first few lines, all the values return to zero. Is there anyway I can prevent that? If I don't define them then it won't work, but there seems to be no way the program can read the file and get their values to use in the program. Is it because I'm saving them as text?

Comment: Use a `std::vector`, use `std::lower_bound` to find where to insert the new score, and then use `std::vector::insert` to insert it (you can always call `pop_back` to get rid of the sixth position). The code becomes so much more readable and you can increase the leaderboard size as much as you want.

Comment: All the scores are set to 0, there is no loop to set multiple values. You don't show how you try to read them back from file. What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your are only reading one value from standard input (cin)
**cin>>score0;**
using this value to initialize the variables (copying the value to score1 and copying to the rest 0).

And latter saving this scores 1,0,0,0,0 to the file.

I think you are forgetting reading from **highscores.txt** file the previous saved high scores (if any) and use this for calculating the updated 5 high scores.

The plan should be:
1-read the high scores from file (using ifstream, probably there would be less than 5 high scores, as in the begining, even the file probably don't exist or is empty:

```
std::ifstream ifs("Highscores.txt");
if (!ifs.eof()) ifs >> score1;
if (!ifs.eof()) ifs >> score2;
if (!ifs.eof()) ifs >> score2;
if (!ifs.eof()) ifs >> score3;
if (!ifs.eof()) ifs >> score4;
ifs.close()

// your code for update the scores and saving.
```

2-Updating the scores and saving back to the file as your code do.

Comment: Reading the last value in a file does not necessarily mean `eof()` will return `true`. You can't assume there's another number if `eof()` returns `false`. A better test is `if (ifs >> score1)` to actually make sure the score is read successfully.

Comment: This mean that there is no possible way of a high score 0, in the sample code, the first time 4 of 5 high scores are 0, probably this is not the correct behavior, probably there is or probably there are the dummy high scores, if the code that read and write the high score match the eof should be true, the complexity in the sample code is the added text in the high scores: "1. ", "2. ",..., need careful attention when reading the scores to not miss the values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're trying to append data to your textfile instead of re-writing it?
use `fstream` with append `std::fstream::app` arguemnt as follow:

```
void someFunc()
{
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open ("Highscores.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::app);

    fs << "your data or scores or whatever";

    fs.close();
}
```